# Need to ignore dashes (" - ") from apache solr query search

Tags: apache, symfony1, solr, search-engine

I'm building a Symfony 1.4 application using apache solr to search through a music database.  I'm using the tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin to port apache solr to my Symfony 1.4 / Doctrine 1.2 app.  I'm new to using apache solr.

The problem I'm getting is that when I type in the string "Katy Perry - Firework", I get only the results for "Katy Perry" and it seems like everything after the dash "-" in the query is ignored.  If I just enter "KatY Perry Firework", the search works properly and the exact song is retrieved.  I'm not sure why the dash messes up the searching.  I thought the WordDelimiterFilterFactory discards non-alpha-numeric characters.  Are my parameters wrong?

How do I use the tokenizer/filters to ignore dashes or " - " (space dash space) string as I'm pretty sure users will be using dashes in the search bar a lot to delineate song from artist (" - ").

Here's my schemal.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using some sort of application to allow users to search on the data within your search engine, why not strip out the hyphen before submitting to solr?

Comment: Thanks for the note Mike.  Yes I'm parsing the query text and submitting it to Solr.  I can definitely do that and replace " - " with spaces or something but I was wondering if there's a more elegant/modular way of doing that so it's all handled by Solr.

Comment: Gotcha. I had to scrub my data before submitting, so I marked this question as a fav, see if there is a better way.

Comment: Are you escaping your queries somehow? Have you had a look at how they are parsed in Solr through the analysis page?

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters have a special function in Lucene (Solr). [Read this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) to find out which and how to escape them.